# Show the parameters sent to the report

Tags: crystal-reports

I must modify a report with crystal reports 8, I know the basics but with very little experience.
Sometimes it works, sometime it show all blank fields, there's a debug option, or a way to show the parameters sent from the program to the report file, and maybe the query that it uses to pick info from the database?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to debug:

1. To know what filtering is applied go to `Report --> selection formula --> report`
2. To see the database query go to `Database ---> Show SQl Query`
3. To see the parameters that are selected during the input, you can drag the parameters onto the Report footer so that when you preview you can see the entered data.